# Token based voting approach

Tags: voting

I want to implement a voting approach and already watched some tutorials. My question is: Is it possible to send out voting tokens to voters that also gather data about the voters? Like for example age or gender? How would the concept of this contract look like?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking it a little bit wrong way, I'd say.

A token contract is a simple smart contract which basically only 1) contains a ledger which says how many tokens each address has and 2) has functionality to transfer those tokens.

I'm not aware of any token standard which couldn't be transferred freely - probably such exist but they are not commonly used. Therefore you can simply write a contract which is like an ERC20 token contract (or maybe even similar to ERC721 if you want to assign other data (age, gender) to the tokens) but doesn't allow transfers for users - only admin can transfer tokens. Then you can assign such voting tokens with some properties to whoever you want and they can use the tokens for voting - of course your contract should also have some functionality to "redeem" those tokens when users vote with them.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into the ERC721 token.

Answer (score 0):

No. I don't think that model maps well to the subject matter it's supposed to represent.

*In my opinion,* tokens are transferrable assets and they are ill-suited to non-transferrable properties of users, entities or things that might possess voting tokens for a time.

It would make perfect sense to say that a 52-year old male *has three voting tokens*. In my mind it does not make sense to say there are three voting tokens that are 52 years old and male. Problems will surface when trying to implement processes like transferring voting privileges (vote by Proxy?) or lending/selling privileges to another user. If votes are modeled as privileges *owned by* users with certain properties, then processes of earning the tokens, transferring, lending will be much easier to reason about.

As a starting point, I would go with votes that are transferrable between users with certain properties. Demographic analysis would still be possible. Rather than tallying up properties of the tokens in the ballot box, it would be modeled as properties of the voters who put them there.

Hope it helps.